# Implement a custom message handler to log the response time HttpClient .net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-5

I have implemented a simple custom message handler to log the time that takes a call.

My startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient(nameof(HttpClient))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<AppmetricsExternalCallMessageHandler>();
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "HttpClient", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

The custom handler

```
public class AppmetricsExternalCallMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<AppmetricsExternalCallMessageHandler> _logger;

    public AppmetricsExternalCallMessageHandler(ILogger<AppmetricsExternalCallMessageHandler> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            var res = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            _logger.LogInformation(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), request.RequestUri.LocalPath);

            return res;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), request.RequestUri.LocalPath);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

and now i have created an end point which call a dummy api using `HttpClientFactory`

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public WeatherForecastController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("test")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(HttpClient));

        //var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return Ok();

        return BadRequest();
    }
    ...
}
```

when i call the endpoint i get an error

> No service for type 'HttpClient.AppmetricsExternalCallMessageHandler'
> has been registered.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.<>c__4`1.b__4_1(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder
> b)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.g__Configure|0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder
> b)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.LoggingHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder
> builder)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandlerEntry(String
> name)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<.ctor>b__1()

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not using the client you've configured (`.AddHttpClient(nameof(HttpClient))`). Specify the name when creating a client `_clientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(HttpClient))`.

Comment: @abdusco yes you are right , update the post because i get aniother error

Comment: Add `services.AddScoped<AppmetricsExternalCallMessageHandler>()`

Comment: @abdusco thank you very much again, is it a good approach to register a handler as a singleton?

Comment: No, ASP.NET Core caches/pools the handlers itself. Let it control handler lifetimes for you. Stick to Transient & Scoped unless you know you need a singleton (usually to cache a global state). Also add `using var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()`. You need to dispose timers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, work with dotnet 6.0
No need to add a httpclient

```
services.AddHttpClient();
        services.ConfigureAll<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(b => b.AdditionalHandlers.Add(new CustomMessageHandler()));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **register** your handler class

in **Startup.cs** in `ConfigureServices` you can register your handler with your preferred  **scope**, like this

```
services.AddScoped<AppmetricsExternalCallMessageHandler>();
```